# spatstat::plot.envelope observed line longer than significance band

Tags: r, simulation, spatial, point-process, spatstat

Using the R package `spatstat` I'm plotting pooled pointwise envelopes of the function Jfox calculated for different point pattern in an hyperframe.

The workflow is as follow:

```
# define distances to make envelopes comparables
ers<-seq(from=0,to=3, by=0.01) 

# calculate the envelopes for the Jfox function for each point pattern in an hyperframe
urc_hyp$env_Jfox<-with(urc_hyp, envelope(Y=urc_ppp,  fun=Jfox, funargs=list(Y=pref_im), r=ers,nsim=39, fix.n=T,savefuns=TRUE, global=FALSE, nrank=1, correction='best', eps=0.1)

# split the hyperframe according to a factor
env_split<-split(urc_hyp$env_Jfox, urc_hyp$matrix)
# pool the envelopes for patterns splitted by factor
env_pool <- anylapply(env_split, FUN= pool)
```

You can find the `env_pool` object [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wytxe5evnqk42u9/AAAnV-SQv0LCB6x8M27A8r0oa?dl=0).
I can see that each envelope has an attribute of suggested *(r)* values:

```
env_pool[[1]]
```

```
Pointwise critical envelopes for J[fox](r)
and observed value for ‘urc_ppp’
Obtained from 78 simulations of CSR with fixed number of points
Alternative: two.sided
Significance level of pointwise Monte Carlo test: 2/79 = 0.0253
..................................................................................
     Math.label             Description                                           
r    r                      distance argument r                                   
obs  {hat(J)[fox]^{obs}}(r) observed value of J[fox](r) for data pattern          
theo {J[fox]^{theo}}(r)     theoretical value of J[fox](r) for CSR                
lo   {hat(J)[fox]^{lo}}(r)  lower pointwise envelope of J[fox](r) from simulations
hi   {hat(J)[fox]^{hi}}(r)  upper pointwise envelope of J[fox](r) from simulations
..................................................................................
Default plot formula:  .~r
where “.” stands for ‘obs’, ‘theo’, ‘hi’, ‘lo’
Columns ‘lo’ and ‘hi’ will be plotted as shading (by default)
Recommended range of argument r: [0, 0.46]
Available range of argument r: [0, 3]
```

So here, for example, the recomended rance goes from 0 to 0.46, while the available range is up to 3 (which is the limit I set to all the envelopes to make them comprable).

Now if I plot without specifying the range of the x axis, the plot function use by default the recomended range:

```
 plot(env_pool[[1]])
```

[image]

but If I specify the xlim I get this:

```
 plot(env_pool[[1]], xlim=c(0,3) )
```

[image]

Now, in the last figure you can see that the shaded area (which represents the significant band, as per `?envelope`) extend beyond the recomended range for *r*.

However the shading does not extend to the whole length of the black line (i.e. the observed JFox curve).

In some case the shading falls short even within the recommended *r* range (e.g. `plot(env_pool[[2]]`)

Is there theoretical a reason for this and if so how should I interpret the line after the shading?

Or is it due to some plotting parameter that should be modified/specified?

Comment: It is counterproductive to repost your question, because that separates the two threads.  To keep them together, I have therefore undeleted your original and closed this one as a duplicate.

Comment: Ok sorry. Wasn't sure what to do...